# FOSRestBundle doesn't work in Symfony 4.1

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have problem with returning views with FOSRestBundle working under Symfony 4.1 Project.

This is code from my controller:

```
class NewsController extends FOSRestController
{

    public function getNewsAction()
    {
        $data = ['news1', 'news2'];

        $view = $this->view($data, 200);

        return $this->handleView($view);
     }
}
```

fos_rest.yaml

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener:  true
    allowed_methods_listener:  true
    routing_loader: true
    view:
        view_response_listener:  'force'
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/api, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json, html ] }
```

framework.yaml

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    php_errors:
        log: true

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:        { annotations: true }
```

So I have pretty basic configuration, and I am still getting errors like this:

> (1/1) RuntimeException
>   You must enable the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle view annotations to use the ViewResponseListener.

I tried to remove "view: view_response_listener: 'force'", but then I am having this error:

> An instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface >must be injected in FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler to render templates.

I'am struggling with it for hours. Is it because of Symfony 4 beta status? Or maybe I am doing something wrong? Maybe I miss some dependecies? I couldn't find anything helpful about this problem in official documentation.

Comment: Might be related to [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25103) By the way, 4.1 would be the master development version.  4.0 is only in the release candidate stage.

Comment: And according to the [bundle compatibility spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mFHQPp9uKtQTFjOBShIoPNHYgmkjHHdskdrd2C0BaF8/edit#gid=1730100865) fosrestbundle does not yet support 4.x.  Not a huge surprise.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add line to `config/packages/framework.yaml`

```
framework:
    templating: { engines: ['twig'] }
```

it will solve

> An instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface >must be injected in FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler to render templates.

Comment: It works, but what I don't understand, that I already use twig in my project. Why do I have to add in the generic framework-config when I want to use it in the ViewHandler?

Answer (score 12):

Do you send the `Accept: application/json` in your request?

If not, you do not necessarily need `twig`, but you need to remove `html` from the format configuration in the bundle config:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json ] }
```

The default is to have `html` in the priorities, and that requires `twig`.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem for me with Symfony 4.1.

Comment: This should be the correct answer!
If you want to use json response for all routes, the rule {fallback_format: json} is just enough!

Answer (score 2):

> You must enable the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle view annotations

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view:        { annotations: false }
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake with copy pasting. It doesn't work for true and false value.

Answer (score 0):

Templating component integration is [deprecated](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-deprecated-the-templating-component-integration) in Symfony 4.3. So *templating* section must be removed (or commented) from config/packages/framework.yaml

```
framework:
    # templating: { engines: ['twig'] }
```

To define Twig as templating service in ViewHandler add lines below to config/services.yaml

```
    fos_rest.templating:
        alias: twig
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: Alexander Matrosov suggest add templating line to config to resolve last error from question (i can not add comment answers now). But it is deprecated solution in Symfony 4.3.